# Javascript Date object to Date String

Tags: javascript, json, date

How can I convert the below 
Javascript Date object `Mon Apr 03 1978 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

to

Date string `/Date(260409600000)/`.

My server returns as JSON string like `"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(260409600000)\/"` so we need to format the normal Date value to this type to process further.

var myDateObj;//Mon Apr 03 1978 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

I tired using Date.parse(myDateObj), but gives only `260409600000`

Also calling `new Date(260409600000).toJSON()` gives `1978-04-03T00:00:00.000Z` and not `/Date(260409600000)/`

Comment: Uhm, so you want `260409600000` and you're getting `260409600000`, what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: So the problem is that you have `260409600000`, but you want `Date(260409600000)` string?

Comment: @dfsq, I am trying to get the same json formated string value by calling toJSON. But it returns different

Comment: Just create custom function or redefine toJSON method.

Answer (score 1):

To convert `260409600000` into `/Date(260409600000)/` you can use the `+` operator:

```
var output = "/Date(" + 260409600000 + ")/";
```

Your confusion probably comes from a wrong assumption that JSON has some kind of date/time data type. It doesn't: what you want to get is nothing but a custom string.